# Turn off devel in DRUPAL manually in database

Tags: php, drupal, module, drupal-7, drupal-modules

How can Drupal 7's DEVEL module be turned off manually by accessing the database?    I activated DEVEL module in Drupal and immediately all configuration pages have started generating Internal Error messages, 500.   I can not get to the DEVEL configuration page nor the MODULE configuration page to disable the DEVEL module, they are among the pages returning the Error 500 message.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to your database manager
2. Look up the "system" table
3. You will find a row where the "name" column contains "devel"
4. Change the "status" field of that row to 0

Comment: The cache will need to be cleared too (The `cache_bootstrap` table specifically if I remember rightly)

Comment: Muhammad, Thank you for the information.   The information is good, but, apparently my estimate of the situation was wrong, this did not solve my problem.

Comment: Perhaps that is my problem, I did not clear the cashe because I can not get to the option to clear cashe.   It is on a configuration page that is hidden by the Internal Error 500 condition.

Comment: My problem may not actually be DEVEL module as a whole, and disabling it may not be adequate.  THe actual problem was enableing the Page Array dump via the DEVEL module.    After turning off the DEVEL module by adjusting status, the condition still exists.  I guess disableing DEVEL does not turn off the Page array dump.

Comment: Is there a way to turn off the Page Array Dump?

Comment: For those that may have this problem (DEVEL Module Page Array dump causing 500 Error), I have determined how to solve the problem. (1) in modules/devel/devel.module, comment out dpm($page, 'page') in the function devel_page_alter, the error will have vanished alone with the attempt to dump Page Array.   (2) disable DEVEL Module.  (3) uninstall DEVEL Module, (4) reinstall DEVEL Module, (5) restore devel.module function devel_page_alter to the original state. Everything will be normal again.